# MS-SQL Bulk Insert with RODBC

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

Is it possible to perform a bulk insert into an MS-SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008) using the RODBC package?

I know that I can do this using freebcp, but I'm curious if the RODBC package implements this portion of the Microsoft SQL API and if not, how difficult it would be to implement it.

Answer (score 6):

check out the new `odbc` and `DBI` packages. `DBI::dbWriteTable` writes around 20,000 records per second... Much much faster than the Row Inserts from `RODBC::sqlSave()`

Comment: I cannot install `odbc`, it generates error: `ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'blob'`

Comment: That sounds like it requires a different question

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [`?sqlSave`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rodbc/docs/sqlUpdate) which uses a parametrized `INSERT INTO` query (taking place in one operation) when you set `Fast=True`.

Comment: Nah, sqlSave will do multiple INSERTS.  I want a BULK INSERT which is a single transaction.

Comment: does fast=true not do it as a single transaction?

Comment: from the rodbc docs: "logical. If false, write data a row at a time. If true, use a parametrized INSERT INTO or UPDATE query to write all the data in one operation."..however it doesn't seem to make any difference (when writing to Netezza in my case)

Comment: I am afraid in my experience setting fast = T or fast = F doesn't change a thing. Records are inserted one by one no matter what. At least in my case with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: For me, fast = TRUE, makes the sqlSave function ~ 3 times faster. Also on sql server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Now You can use  `dbBulkCopy`  from the new [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver)  package:

A typical scenario:

1. You create a matrix
2. you save it as a csv file
3. You call `dbBulkCopy` to read fil and insert it using internally `bcp` tool of MS Sql server.

This assume that your table is already created in the data base:

```
dat <- matrix(round(rnorm(nrow*ncol),nrow,ncol)
id.file = "temp_file.csv"                      
write.csv(dat,file=id.file,row.names=FALSE)
dbBulkCopy(conn,'NEW_BP_TABLE',value=id.file)
```

Comment: any reason why rsqlserver is not on cran?

Comment: @MusX because it is under development(specially documentation and tests part) and it uses `rClr` package which is not on CRAN too.  But you are encouraged to use it from GITHUB and will be happy with any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Using RODBC, the fastest insert we've been able to create (260 million row insert) looks like the following (in R pseudo code):

```
ourDataFrame <- sqlQuery(OurConnection, "SELECT myDataThing1, myDataThing2
                                         FROM myData")
ourDF <- doStuff(ourDataFrame)
write.csv(ourDF,ourFile)  
sqlQuery(OurConnection, "CREATE TABLE myTable ( la [La], laLa [LaLa]);
                         BULK INSERT myTable FROM 'ourFile' 
                              WITH YOURPARAMS=yourParams;")
```

If you're running this from between servers, you need a network drive that the R server can write to (e.g. one server with permissions for writing to the DB uses Rscript to productionalize the code), and the SQL Server can read from.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I can find, there is NO solution for bulk insert to MySQL and nothing that works with SSIS which is why Microsoft is including in-database analytics with SQL Server 2016 after buying Revolution R Analytics.

I tried to comment on the previous answer but don't have the reputation to do it.

The `rsqlserver` package needs to run with `rClr` and neither of those packages are well-behaved, especially because `rsqlserver`'s INSERT functions have poor data type handling. So if you use it, you'll have no idea what you're looking at in the SQL table as much of the information in your data.frame will have been transformed.

Considering the `RODBC` package has been around for 15 years, I'm pretty disappointed that no one has created a bulk insert function...

Comment: important point on rsqlserver, but for many of us we don't need to 'look at' the data (from an R standpoint).  If it's been modeled and shaped and processed in R we just need the result back in the database and it doesnt matter what R transforms the type to in the database (as long as they are reasonable and can be read by other systems)

Comment: @Joe I don't think I'd ever hire someone who says "we don't need to 'look at' the data".

Answer (score 1):

Our `n2khelper` package can use `bcp` (bulkcopy) when it is available. When not available it falls back to multiple INSERT statements.

You can find the package on https://github.com/INBO-Natura2000/n2khelper

Install it with `devtools::install_git("INBO-Natura2000/n2khelper")` and look for the `odbc_insert()` function.